# Error when using PEAKachu for peak calling

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to use [PEAKachu](https://github.com/tbischler/PEAKachu/tree/master/peakachulib) to call peaks for RNA eclip pair-end data. I installed PEAKachu on slurm by building from the source:

```
make readme_rst
make package
pip3 install --user dist/PEAKachu-0.2.0.tar.gz
```

Then, I used the command to run PEAKachu:

```
peakachu adaptive -M 200 -m 0.0 -Q 0.05 -c control.bam -t experiment.bam  -o peakachu
```

But it returned an error after running for 1 minute:

```
** Converting reads to bed format for 1 libraries...
expdupsorted generated an exception: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/jet/home/li6/.local/bin/peakachu", line 162, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/jet/home/li6/.local/bin/peakachu", line 140, in main
    args.func(controller)
  File "/jet/home/li6/.local/bin/peakachu", line 150, in adaptive_approach
    controller.adaptive_approach()
  File "/jet/home/li6/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peakachulib/controller.py", line 131, in adaptive_approach
    adaptive.generate_combined_bed_file()
  File "/jet/home/li6/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peakachulib/adaptive.py", line 84, in generate_combined_bed_file
    replicon]["reads"].add(lib.replicon_dict[replicon][
KeyError: 'reads'
```

I am so confused because I tracked back to see what the code was doing, and the relevant part of [code](https://github.com/tbischler/PEAKachu/blob/master/peakachulib/adaptive.py) is:

```
80 for replicon in sorted(self._replicon_dict):
81             self._replicon_dict[replicon]["reads"] = pd.Series()
82             for lib_name, lib in exp_lib_dict.items():
83                 self._replicon_dict[replicon]["reads"] = self._replicon_dict[
84                    replicon]["reads"].add(lib.replicon_dict[replicon][
85                        "reads"], fill_value=0)
```

As in line 81, it has created the key "reads" for _replicon_dict[replicon], how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a similar issue as yours. I noticed this error had to do with some deprecated functions in the pandas library, thus downgrading pandas to 1.4.0 solved the issue, i.e.:

```
mamba create -c bioconda -n peakachu peakachu pandas==1.4.0
```